# Windows Server 2012, This site can’t be reached "" server DNS address could not be found

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, iis, dns

I have my website deployed in Windows Azure Virtual machine and configured in IIS server. When i do a local explore from the web server its working fine with the local host and i can able to see my website and navigate it properly.

But when i try to access it from public network with the public DNS which azure provides I am getting the error as below.

This site can’t be reached

www.f5debug.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Go to http://www.azure.com/
Search Google for f5debug east asia cloudapp azure Home
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

If I can deploy a simple website (sample website with asp.net) and try to access with the same DNS its working fine.

I am not sure as this website is working perfect in a hosting provider (databasemart.com) and when i try to move it to azure its getting this issue.

Kindly help me with some pointers if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any redirection rules defined in your web application? For some reason, `www` gets prepended to your URL. When I type in `http://f5debug.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com`, I get redirected to `http://www.f5debug.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com`.

Comment: No Sir, I was surprised to see that it prepends www to the request. There is no such rule and the same code works fine with another server where the application is deployed already. When moving to Azure it happens like this and i am clueless on where to debug, if its the DNS issue then Azure dont provide an interface to debug it I believe.

Comment: @GauravMantri - I don't - I just get a 404. From the DNS I see `f5debug.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com has address 207.46.138.131`  and for www `Host www.f5debug.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a DNS issue. The DNS record f5debug.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com is the Azure-provided DNS record for this service and it is resolving correctly to the VIP listed above.

Whatever the issue here, it is occuring after the client is hitting your service - after the Azure-provided DNS record is resolved.

As others have stated above, this is likely a service-side redirect to www.f5debug.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com. Hopefully knowing that the DNS is working fine will allow you to focus your investigations on your deployed serivce.

Regards,
Stephen Malone - Azure Networking